# jQuery converting datetime to specific format

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I have a datetime which gets returned from server side in my .net application like following:

```
Jul 24 2017  7:33PM
```

I have tried to convert it  into:

```
yyyy-MM-dd
```

format like following:

```
var date = new Date(data);
 var res = (date.getFullYear() + '-'(date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate());
```

But when I output the result in console the result I get is:

```
NaN-NaN-NaN
```

How can I convert the time in jQuery/Javascript into  `yyyy-MM-dd`  format?

Can someone help me out?

P.S. Guys here is the query that returns the results and dates that I'm trying to convert:

```
     var user = ctx.Users.Where(x => x.UserId == _parsedId)
                .Select(b => new
                {
                    Active = b.Active,
                    Email = b.Email,
                    Subscriptions = b.Subscriptions.Where(p => p.Active == true).Select(sub => new
                    {
                        SubscriptionID = sub.SubscriptionId,
                        Type = sub.SubTypes.SubName,
                        ReferenceID = sub.ReferenceId,
                        Active = sub.Active,
                        DateCreated = sub.CreateDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                        ExpirationDate = sub.ExpirationDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                    }).ToList(),
                    Roles = b.UserRoles.Where(p => p.Active == true).ToList()
                })
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(x => x)
                .FirstOrDefault();


   // ExpirationDate - is of Type DateTime?
   // CreatedDate - is of Type DateTime
```

And when I try to convert the datetime to specific format I get a following error:

> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: If possible, make the server output a better structured format such as the `yyyy-MM-dd` that you mentioned. Would save a lot of headaches on the client side.

Comment: `new Date(Jul 24 2017  7:33PM);` returns `InvalidDate`

Comment: "Note: Parsing of strings with Date.parse is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies." (Date.parse is what uses the constructor when string passed) - [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: @StephenMuecke A yes, I guess Peter made a good suggestion to change it in server side and avoid conversions in client side ... ?

Comment: Guys, I've pasted my server side code with conversion to specific format, but I'm getting an error here...

Comment: If you can use the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library you can do something like this `moment("Jul 24 2017  7:33PM", "MMM DD YYYY hh:mmA").format("DD-MM-YYYY")`

Comment: You can always make the property `string`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm using an anonymous type, would that be even possible? xD

Comment: Yes, but only my materializing the query first ( `ctx.Users.Where(x => x.UserId == _parsedId).AsEnumerable().Select(...` ) and then converting to a formatted string. But how are you using this and why do you need it in that format

Comment: @StephenMuecke hm this is quite odd, when doing AsEnumerable() I'm getting empty collections Subscriptions and Roles, but I know for a fact they should have at least 2 elements inside ? :/

Comment: did you try sub.CreateDate.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") ??

Comment: You might need a `.Include(x => x.Subscriptions)` etc

Comment: @StephenMuecke a yes correct , gonan try it now =)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I did include all nearby tables and I'm getting circular reference error now xD

Comment: Best guess is that `UserRoles` contains a reference back to `Users`, and that you returning a `JsonResult` - you should also create an anonymous object for `Roles` containing only the properties your need. (note also you do not need your `.Select(x => x)`)

Comment: alert(date); and check is it giving correct date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always use moment.js ( http://momentjs.com/ )

It's one of the easiest methods to manipulate with Date and Time.

Using moment you can easily covert by :

```
moment(new Date()).format('yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Comment: Hey Sagar, by doing this , for example input date: Jul 24 2017  7:33PM gets output like: 2017-10-03  , which isn't correct at all

Comment: Hello there, I tried and got the correct result. Can you please send the exact date so I can recheck.

Answer (score 2):

```
moment(yourdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm').format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change your server side code,

```
var user = ctx.Users.Where(x => x.UserId == _parsedId)
            .Select(b => new
            {
                Active = b.Active,
                Email = b.Email,
                Subscriptions = b.Subscriptions.Where(p => p.Active == true).ToList().Select(sub => new
                {
                    SubscriptionID = sub.SubscriptionId,
                    Type = sub.SubTypes.SubName,
                    ReferenceID = sub.ReferenceId,
                    Active = sub.Active,
                    DateCreated = sub.CreateDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                    ExpirationDate = sub.ExpirationDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                }).ToList(),
                Roles = b.UserRoles.Where(p => p.Active == true).ToList()
            })
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(x => x)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

this is work for you